# Why are strings chosen over loops?

Tags: string-theory, quantum-gravity, loop-quantum-gravity

The basis of my question is as follows:

I am very aware that, within the realm of quantum gravity research, string theory is a far more popular formulation than loop quantum gravity (LQG). Why is this? Is there a reason that strings are more attractive, or perhaps is there something predicted by LQG which is considered unattractive? Personally, I could imagine a mindset where LQG is a far more attractive and natural option, so why is it considered an "alternative" quantum gravity description?

I am mostly looking for objective/physical/historical reasons.

Comment: Hi Bob. This is the sort of thing we discuss in the chat room, but it's too broad a question for the main site.

Comment: Strings reproduce all the phenomena of QFT and gravity, loops reproduce none of them.

Comment: One reason is that string theory not only quantizes gravity consistently (at least at the pertubative level), but simultaneously unifies the fundamental forces of nature. On the other hand loop quantum gravity only quantizes gravity and does not require the other forces of nature to appear in the theory.

Comment: @MitchellPorter what you say is technically false. It is known that loops reproduce exactly General Relativity, no more and no less – in the classical limit (I am talking about the modern spinfoam formulation, for the canonical formulation there's still no consensus on the classical limit).

Comment: @SolenodonParadoxus Can you give a reference? I want to see this for myself.

Comment: @MitchellPorter sure, start with https://arxiv.org/abs/1201.2187 (I believe it is the original paper showing this, but there's a good chance that I'm wrong about this). But it is also treated in great detail in Rovelli's textbook "Covariant Loop Quantum Gravity", and references therein. Maybe it is a better reference (I always prefer the textbook version to arxiv papers when it is available).

Comment: @MitchellPorter the textbook is freely distributed here http://www.cpt.univ-mrs.fr/~rovelli/IntroductionLQG.pdf  Chapter 8 is dedicated entirely to the classical limit.

Comment: @SolenodonParadoxus Thanks. I reserve judgment - there may still be handwaving, when you get into the details - and I note that Rovelli & Vidotto don't cite any of these recent papers by Engle where the EPRL vertex is supposedly fixed. But unlike the canonical formulation (which is inconsistent with ordinary QFT e.g. the chiral anomaly becomes impossible), I would not be too surprised to find that some version of the covariant formulation really does give you GR; and these resources (e.g. R&V's table 8.1) will help me the next time I have a serious discussion about LQG.

Comment: @MitchellPorter well I've studied the details thoroughly, and I don't see any handwaving there. In fact, there's an unambiguous mathematical algorithm to recover the classical effective action directly from the spinfoam amplitude, which is based on plugging in coherent states, evaluating the integral via the stationary phase approximation and taking the $\hbar \rightarrow 0$ limit. If you do this for the EPRL vertex, you get Einstein-Hilbert action. They even managed to compute some properties of the graviton propagator from semiclassical LQG. Other matter fields aren't reproduced, though.